# Template Static library with template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

I am working on a static library and the library has multiple class templates and function templates. I understand in order to use the templates inside static library everything (declaration/definition) needs to be in the header file. However, in this particular case since I know the specialization types I thought I can use forward declare the specialization instead.

This trick works nicely with the class templates (and its functions) and I can use all the library function from my application code. However, as soon as I introduce free function template inside the library and I try to use the free templated function from my application code it gives me linker error:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class
>   TemplatedStaticLib __cdecl HelpingRegistration(int)"
>   (??$HelpingRegistration@H@@YA?AV?$TemplatedStaticLib@H@@H@Z)
>   referenced in function _main
>   1>C:\src\cpp\vs2008\StaticLibExample\MathFuncsLib\Debug\TemplatedStaticLibApp.exe
>   : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals"
>   I am using VS2008, here is the code

//Static library header file (.h)

```
#ifndef _TEMPLATED_STATIC_LIB_
#define _TEMPLATED_STATIC_LIB_

#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class TemplatedStaticLib
{
public:
    TemplatedStaticLib(){};
    ~TemplatedStaticLib(){};

    void print(T t);

};

template<typename T>
TemplatedStaticLib<T> HelpingRegistration(T);


#endif
```

//static library class file (.cpp)

```
#include "TemplatedStaticLib.h"

//Specialization
template class TemplatedStaticLib<double>;
template class TemplatedStaticLib<int>;
template class TemplatedStaticLib<std::string>;


template<typename T>
void TemplatedStaticLib<T>::print(T t)
{
    std::cout << "Templated Print "  << typeid(t).name() << std::endl;
}

void HelpingRegistration(void)
{
}

//Specialization of free function
template<> TemplatedStaticLib<int> HelpingRegistration<int>(int);
template<> TemplatedStaticLib<double> HelpingRegistration<double>(double);
template<> TemplatedStaticLib<std::string> HelpingRegistration<std::string>(std::string);

template<typename T>
TemplatedStaticLib<T> HelpingRegistration(T t)
{
       std::cout << "Function Templated Print "  << typeid(t).name() << std::endl;
       return t;
}
```

//Application code

```
#include "TemplatedStaticLib.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int anInt = 99;
    TemplatedStaticLib<int> test; 
    test.print(anInt);//works

    double aDouble = 3.9;
    TemplatedStaticLib<double> double_test; 
    double_test.print(aDouble); //works

    std::string aString = "James";

    TemplatedStaticLib<std::string> string_test; 
    string_test.print(aString);//works

    //The following lines gives linker error
    HelpingRegistration(anInt);
    HelpingRegistration(aDouble);
    HelpingRegistration(aString);


    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure why it is different and how I can fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Templates can't be defined across translation units.

Comment: classic example of template abuse

Comment: Hmm I am wondering why it works for class template case then ?

Comment: @Aniket: I do not think so. The OP just declared function template specialization rather than explicitly instantiating the function template.

Comment: @David: They can, as long as you provide explicit instantiations for all the instantiations you implicitly require in other translation units.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mind the fact that those are **not** forward declarations, but rather *explicit instantiations* of your class templates. That is what allows you to put the definition in a `.cpp` files and get no unresolved reference error by the linker, as long as in other translation units you only use those template instantiations.

On the other hand, these:

```
template<> TemplatedStaticLib<int> HelpingRegistration<int>(int);
template<> TemplatedStaticLib<double> HelpingRegistration<double>(double);
template<> TemplatedStaticLib<std::string> HelpingRegistration<std::string>(std::string);
```

are declarations of *explicit specializations* of function templates. What you most likely intended to do is, instead, to provide **explicit instantiations**. The syntax for doing that is the following:

```
template TemplatedStaticLib<int> HelpingRegistration<>(int);
template TemplatedStaticLib<double> HelpingRegistration<>(double);
template TemplatedStaticLib<std::string> HelpingRegistration<>(std::string);
```

Once you will fix that, you will see that the compiler will actually *instantiate* your `HelpingRegistration<>()` function template, and it will also emit an error while doing so, because you are trying to convert an `int` (resp. a `double` or `string`) to an object of type `TemplatedStaticLib<int>` (resp. `TemplatedStaticLib<double>` or `TemplatedStaticLib<string>`), for which no conversion is provided (or at least not shown in the code you posted):

```
template<typename T>
TemplatedStaticLib<T> HelpingRegistration(T t)
{
    std::cout << "Function Templated Print "  << typeid(t).name() << std::endl;
    return t; // CANNOT BE CONVERTED!
}
```

Fixing this error (e.g. by doing `return TemplateStaticLib<T>();`) will make the program compile *and* link.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clue @Andy, all I needed is Explicit Instantiation of function templates not Explicit Specialization and thanks for pointing out the conversion issue as well. Actually didn't need to convert at all. so I modified the Specialization template<> TemplatedStaticLib<int> HelpingRegistration<int>(int) to template void HelpingRegistration<int>(int t) and all works like a charm.